# BASH: run commands asynchronously at a delay

Tags: bash, delay

Effectively what I'm trying to accomplish is the following, where cmd1 takes a while to run (~1 minute) and cmd2 returns almost instantly whenever run:

1. cmd1 starts
2. wait a little while (~10 seconds)
3. cmd2 runs
4. wait a little while again
5. cmd2 runs again
6. some time passes
7. cmd1 finishes

It is essential this be scripted since it has got to go inside a rather large loop, which runs cmd1 with many different parameters, and then does the same all over again for several other longish-running commands.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
cmd1 &
cmd1_pid=$!
sleep 10
cmd2
sleep 10
cmd2
wait $cmd1_pid
```

explanation: `cmd1 &` launches a process in the background of the shell. the `$!` variable contains the pid of that background process. the shell keeps processing the other cmds. `sleep 10` means 'wait a little while'. OP just wants to fire `cmd2` in linear order so that part is trivial. at the end of the script snippet we just wait for `cmd1` to finish (it might be even finished earlier) with `wait $cmd1_pid`.

Comment: thanks! I don't think this exactly solves the use case i have above, but I expect I can modify it slightly so as to do what i need :)

Comment: oh sorry I didn't mean to imply that any part of it was still opaque to me, just that this doesn't (unless I misunderstand your answer?) exactly follow the steps I posted above - i'm marking this accepted as soon as SU lets me

Comment: i changed the solution to mimic directly your 7 steps

Comment: awesome - i thought that was what was different :) Thanks for teaching me about the pid/wait stuff! I'm sure that'll come in handy a lot in the future as well

Comment: it was different a little bit :) in the first draft i ran `cmd1` and `cmd2` both in background. but your first statement already showed that you grabbed the concept the first time already, nevertheless i wanted to answer the original problem as good as possible. so .. :)

Comment: @akira You wrote 'wait' in the code snippet, and then 'waitpid' in the text - I'm assuming it should be the same (which one?) in both places?

Comment: @DavidDoria: fixed.

Comment: You don't need to store the PID. Just use `wait` to wait for all background jobs to finish or in the rare case you need to wait for just one specific background job, use `wait %1` (1 being the job id in this example). For more advanced scripts, use `coproc MYCMD { cmd1; }`, then `wait $MYCMD_PID`.

Comment: @StefanSeidel: "7. cmd1 finishes.", that's why i `wait` for it. `coproc` is a 4er-bashism, might not be available in other shells. using `%1` instead of storing the pid sucks in terms of "start a new command here and there and start counting started processes".